# How do can I remove padding from MenuItem in ActionBar

Tags: android

I'm trying to remove MenuItem padding for more than 4 hours, but definitely I'm not able to do that by myself.

I have two aproaches that I've tried. The first one is to get My menuItem and it's view and setPadding to 0:

```
MenuItem back = menu.findItem(R.id.back);
        back.setActionView(R.id.testando);

View bView = (View) back.getActionView();
bView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

The problem in this case is that my bView always returns NULL, I don't know why, cause back is already instatiated...

The other aproach is to get my MenuItem and set a customized View with padding 0:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.browser_menu, menu);

MenuItem back = menu.findItem(R.id.back);
back.setActionView(R.id.testando);
```

testando XML file:

```
<ActionMenuItemView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/testando"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:paddingBottom="0dip"
    android:paddingStart="0dip"
    android:paddingEnd="0dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/actionMenuTextAppearance"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/actionMenuTextColor"
    style="?android:attr/actionButtonStyle" />
```

The problem in this case is caused by ResourcesNotFoundException

```
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0a0046 type #0x12 is not valid
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2112)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:858)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:566)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at br.com.facilit.target.app.android.BrowserActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(BrowserActivity.java:36)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2444)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:388)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:739)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2833)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-17 15:35:39.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Padding of parent also makes child view's spaced out. I don't think there's an easy way to get to Actionbar's parent View that holds MenuItem Views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MenuItem#setActionView takes a layout as its parameter not an id. That is just one one problem, with the above.

I suggest you create a class that extends ImageView then put the class path in the android:actionViewClass attribute on your menu item in the menus Xml.

See: https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/5835584