# How to remove end padding of checkable menu item?

Tags: android, android-menu, android-checkbox, overflow-menu

I have an overflow menu with a checkable menu item. I would like to align the `CheckBox` all the way to the end, but I don't know how this can be done.

My menu is defined like so:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/desktop_site"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:checked="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_desktop_windows_24"
                android:title="Desktop site"
                app:showAsAction="never" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

[image: Overflow menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom style to the `CheckBox` and adjust the end padding with a negative value:

```
<style name="checkbox_style" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:paddingRight">-7dp</item>
</style>
```

And apply it to your app's theme:

```
<item name="checkboxStyle">@style/checkbox_style</item>
```

[image]

**Note:** By default there should be some margin surrounds a menu item; so you can't send the `checkBox` to the far end, as its right edge will cut:

When using -8dp:

[image]

So, you need to be careful in handling this.

**UPDATE**

> but it affects all the `CheckBoxes` in my app

This requires to reverse this padding in all of `CheckBoxes` in your layouts; and there are options for this:

- **First option:** add `android:paddingRight="7dp"` / `android:paddingEnd="7dp"` to all the `CheckBoxes`.
- **Second option:** Create a custom `CheckBox` class and add this padding to its constructors; and use this customized CheckBox instead of the default `CheckBox`:

```
public class MyCheckBox extends AppCompatCheckBox {

    public MyCheckBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                7f, // dp value
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
        );
        setPadding(0, 0, px, 0);
    }

    public MyCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }


}
```

And to use it:

```
<!-- Add the full path of the customized CheckBox -->
<com.example.android......MyCheckBox   
    android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Hint: If you target API-17+, then use `android:paddingEnd` instead `android:paddingRight`

Comment: Also have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154557/how-do-can-i-remove-padding-from-menuitem-in-actionbar)

Comment: This works, but it affects all the CheckBoxes in my app

Comment: @shko Absolutely right; please have a look at the updated answer; hopefully it works now.

Comment: Nice, this is probably the way to do it. Too bad these things can't be styled through `Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow` directly

Comment: @shko Unfortunately there is no direct way as this is special type of checkable; even trying to inflate that using ActionView didn't work; if that solved your problem; thanks to accept the answer.

Comment: I accepted the answer and gave you the bounty now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `PopupWindow`. This allows you to completely customize it.
First create a XML file of your Popup. Using `wrap_content` at the main layout is very important to shrink the Popup to its size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_desktop_mac_24"
            app:tint="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Desktop site"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Then show the dialog by calling this function. (I copied this code from one of my projects, but I can remember I got it from SO).

```
private void showPopup(Context context, Point p) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_popup_xml, null);
    
    PopupWindow changeStatusPopUp = new PopupWindow(context);
    changeStatusPopUp.setContentView(layout);
    changeStatusPopUp.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    changeStatusPopUp.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    changeStatusPopUp.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);

    int OFFSET_X = -300; //Adjust position of the Popup
    int OFFSET_Y = 50;   //Adjust position of the Popup
        
    changeStatusPopUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    changeStatusPopUp.setFocusable(true);
    changeStatusPopUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    changeStatusPopUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);
}
```

If you want to catch Click Events, you just need to set an `id` to the `LinearLayout` and use it with the `view` in Java (`LinearLayout ll = view.findViewById(R.id.yourId);`).

Call the void by:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
Point point = new Point();
point.x = location[0];
point.y = location[1];
showStatusPopup(context, point);
```

Comment: What is p.x and p.y? The PopupWindow is laid out behind my BottomSheet, all the way to the left

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a piece of code. Check my edited answer. I also added the parameter Point p to the void.

Answer (score 0):

When using MaterialComponents some of the padding is from the checkbox itself. This can be removed by setting `android:minWidth` to `0`. The remaining padding is symmetrical and looks good.

Like the accepted solution, create a style:

```
<style name="checkbox_style" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="minWidth">0dp</item>
</style>
```

And apply it to your app's theme:

```
<item name="checkboxStyle">@style/checkbox_style</item>
```